# Un-even grid for minor ticks using AutoDateLocator

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use AutoDateLocator with minor ticks and I'm getting an uneven grid. I'm wondering if this is a bug or if there's something I'm missing.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = [datetime.datetime(2005, 2, 1, 10, 6),
         datetime.datetime(2005, 2, 1, 12, 24)]
y = [1, 10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
minloc = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=10, maxticks=20)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minloc)
ax.plot(dates, y)
ax.grid(which='both')
ax.set_xlim(dates)    
plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You have major ticks every 15 minutes and minor ticks every 10 minutes, so there isn't anything "uneven". Do you want minor ticks to be every 5 minutes instead? If so you could use a `MinuteLocator`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, in this case since the major ticks are on 15-minute intervals I'd like the minor ticks every 5. More generally, I'd like the minor ticks to always be an even division of the major ticks. Is there a way to marry up the AutoDateLocators to make this happen automatically? This is for a general case and I like how the AutoDateLocator and ConciseDateFormatter work for major ticks. I would just like to add minor ticks for a finer grid without crowding the labels.

Comment: `AutoMinorLocator` should help here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator .